# Why does my crypto.createHmac() generate a different HMAC for the same input?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, php, javascript, hmac

I am trying to match the HMAC in Node.js to the HMAC in PHP for API authorization. The problem is in Node.js, the createHmac() function generates a different HMAC for the same input, and therefore does not match with the HMAC in PHP.

Here is my JS code:

```
events: {
  proxyReq: (proxyReq, req) => {
    const API_KEY = 125;
    const API_SECRET_KEY = 'abc';

    let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', API_SECRET_KEY);
    hmac.update('0');
    const s = hmac.digest('base64');

    proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-key', API_KEY);
    proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-signature', s);
    proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-date', date);
  },
```

PHP:

```
$API_SECRET_KEY = 'abc';
$client_signature = $request->header('x-api-signature');
$hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', '0', base64_decode($API_SECRET_KEY), true));

Log::error($client_signature);
Log::error($hmac);
```

Latest outputs:

```
[2018-07-11 15:25:28] local.ERROR: dO50o/LcS0/UOXOu/5lHbOMXLe+l225vUU13fWEHeOoUHV7SlcSOE9rQq2UhTlys5N6C4hkq8QTALnpRehtlCg==  
[2018-07-11 15:25:28] local.ERROR: 7W2U/3uEKIMD0s39jmZLlJItwTcSSDQdW7WTYdslvIjuUeGydyqwwAuZzaMP0Do5v1zRJxmPITFdy4EHTY5r6A==  

[2018-07-11 15:25:33] local.ERROR: UYsXZFyoAB2zELZzwjWyktPEHlYqIP3cgLeb/LXK0X8pnkVxiqEaFWK7c1YIWd6hFPpZHn5j1YdbDhpAL7hQ5A==  
[2018-07-11 15:25:33] local.ERROR: 7W2U/3uEKIMD0s39jmZLlJItwTcSSDQdW7WTYdslvIjuUeGydyqwwAuZzaMP0Do5v1zRJxmPITFdy4EHTY5r6A==
```

Any alternatives or solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're `base64_decode`ing  the secret in PHP but not in Node. Remove the `base64_decode` and you get:

```
gvRZ6BJer/YEkwdJ2OrTetIt1Knza5Vr0ZZ/inV5ySkFW4PBnO77c19L7TFpy9c4FA98/OcK/pB8Gvumwo4CQw==
```

which matches what I get when testing your JavaScript code.